# avoiding the first newline in a C++11 raw string literal?

Tags: c++, c++11

The raw string literals in C++11 are very nice, except that the obvious way to format them leads to a redundant newline `\n` as the first character.

Consider this example:

```
    some_code();
    std::string text = R"(
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
)";
    more_code();
```

The obvious workaround seems so ugly:

```
    some_code();
    std::string text = R"(This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
)";
    more_code();
```

Has anyone found an elegant solution to this?

Comment: I can't remember if `\\n` gets replaced with a space or just joins the lines without any spaces.

Comment: All characters inside the raw string, including newlines and `\\` are interpreted literally.

Comment: put `R"(` in next line

Comment: @Hugues, Never mind. I read through the first phase too quickly.

Comment: @chris In fairness, that note doesn't directly specify anything by itself. It's really in 2.5 [lex.pptoken]: "If the next character begins a sequence of characters that could be the prefix and initial double quote of a raw string literal, such as R", the next preprocessing token shall be a raw string literal. Between the initial and final double quote characters of the raw string, any transformations performed in phases 1 and 2 (trigraphs, universal-character-names, and line splicing) are reverted; this reversion shall apply before any d-char, r-char, or delimiting parenthesis is identified."

Comment: There's nothing elegant about having a string literal not indented per the rest of your code, but if you want multiline raw string literals like this - and for whatever reason don't follow Bryan's sane advice - a less sane way to get what you want is `= 1 + R"(`....

Comment: @hvd, Ah, good point, thanks. Shame it doesn't work, at least until you want a backslash in your string before the newline.

Comment: I was thinking about using newline as the delimiter (`R"` / `(First` / `Second` / `Third)` / `"`), but that doesn't work either: newline is one of the few characters that cannot be used in the delimiter.

Comment: @BryanChen Thanks for suggesting `R"(` on the next line.  It still doesn't align the first text line perfectly though.

Comment: @TonyD I like your suggestion of `= 1 + R"(`; it's very clever.  Could you please post this as an answer?

Comment: @Hugues: done... cheers.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can get a pointer to the 2nd character - skipping the leading newline - by adding 1 to the `const char*` to which the string literal is automatically converted:

```
    some_code();
    std::string text = 1 + R"(
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
)";
    more_code();
```

---

IMHO, the above is flawed in breaking with the indentation of the surrounding code.  Some languages provide a built-in or library function that does something like:

- removes an empty leading line, and
- looks at the indentation of the second line and removes the same amount of indentation from all further lines

That allows usage like:

```
some_code();
std::string text = unindent(R"(
    This is the first line.
    This is the second line.
    This is the third line.
    )");
more_code();
```

Writing such a function is relatively simple...

```
std::string unindent(const char* p)
{
    std::string result;
    if (*p == '\n') ++p;
    const char* p_leading = p;
    while (std::isspace(*p) && *p != '\n')
        ++p;
    size_t leading_len = p - p_leading;
    while (*p)
    {
        result += *p;
        if (*p++ == '\n')
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < leading_len; ++i)
                if (p[i] != p_leading[i])
                    goto dont_skip_leading;
            p += leading_len;
        }
      dont_skip_leading: ;
    }
    return result;
}
```

(The slightly weird `p_leading[i]` approach is intended to make life for people who use tabs and spaces no harder than they make it for themselves ;-P, as long as the lines start with the same sequence.)

Comment: Is it 1 character? Or is it 2?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: in the context being discussed, one.  The compiler may arrange for distinct carriage returns and line feeds to be generated for each `'\n'` during output, but the code and techniques presented above are - I believe - portable regardless of such later conversions.  If you have reason to believe otherwise, please do share.

Comment: I'm just raising a talking point really. Do we know for sure that there is only a newline? Is that guaranteed? Or does it depend on the encoding of the source file? If the latter then your [first] solution is too optimistic.

Comment: The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39886017/11279879). It is 1 character, a single `'\n'`.

Comment: thumbs up for using goto :-)

Comment: 1 + R"(... Might give clang warning: "Adding 'int' to a string does not append to the string". Use 1 + &*R"( to avoid this warning.

Answer (score 10):

This is probably not what you want, but just in case, you should be aware of automatic string literal concatenation:

```
    std::string text =
"This is the first line.\n"
"This is the second line.\n"
"This is the third line.\n";
```

Comment: Why not indent it? ;)

Comment: Note that it also applies to raw literals, so `R"(...)\n"` `R"(...)\n"` ... is also a possibility.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The space between the delimiting quote and paren is reserved for a delimiter character sequence.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Certainly... though I have no idea how it applies to my comment (or this answer)...

Comment: @MatthieuM. It appears that you intended to put the `\n` there and have it encoded into the actual string.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Ah! yes, indeed, `\n` should be interpreted, so `R"(...)""\n"` `R"(...)""\n"` ...

Answer (score 4):

I recommend @Brian's answer, especially if you only need to have few lines of text, or that which you can handle with your text editor-fu. I have an alternative if that isn't the case.

```
    std::string text =
"\
This is the first line." R"(
This is the second line.
This is the third line.)";
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e79704ab47af38f6)

Raw string literals can still concatenate with "normal" string literals, as shown in the code. The `"\` at the start is meant to "eliminate" the `"` character from the first line, putting it in a line of its own instead.

Still, if I were to decide, I would put such lotsa-text into a separate file and load it at runtime. No pressure to you though :-).

<sup><sup><sup>Also, that is one of the uglier code I've written these days.</sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 4):

The closest I can see is:

```
std::string text = ""
R"(This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
)";
```

It would be a bit nicer if a whitespace was allowed in the delimiter sequence. Give or take the indentation:

```
std::string text = R"
    (This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
)
    ";
```

My preprocessor will let you off with a warning about this, but unfortunately it's a bit useless. Clang and GCC get thrown off completely.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer produces the warning [cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-constant-array-index](http://cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-constant-array-index) from `clang-tidy`. See [Pro.bounds: Bounds safety profile](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#probounds-bounds-safety-profile) for details.

If you don't have `std::span` but you're at least compiling with C++17 consider:

```
constexpr auto text = std::string_view(R"(
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
)").substr(1);
```

The main advantages are readability (IMHO) and that you can turn on that clang-tidy warning in the rest of your code.

Using `gcc` if someone does inadvertently reduce the raw string to an empty string you get a compiler error ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2890b1e913a99bfb)) with this approach, while the accepted approach either produces nothing ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6b8eb8632b9e4eb)) or depending on your compiler settings an "outside bounds of constant string" warning.

Comment: *"or depending on your compiler settings an "outside bounds of constant string" warning."* - what compiler setting would produce such a warning?  Empty strings are still guaranteed (by the C++ Standard) to be null terminated....

Answer (score 4):

With C++20 this can now be implemented fully at compile-time by using a [string literal operator template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal#Literal_operators).

That has a few key benefits:

- Only the unindented string will be stored in the resulting binary.
- No allocations, zero runtime overhead
- The resulting value will be a reference to a character array (`const char (&)[N]`) - like normal character literals in C++; so no `std::array` shenanigans and lifetime issues.

Usage Example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rMv49c3x4)

```cpp
std::cout << R"(
     a
    b
     c
    d
)"_M << std::endl;
/* Will print the following:
 a
b
 c
d
*/

// The type of R"(...)"_M is const char (&)[N],
// so it can be used like a normal string literal:
std::cout << std::size(R"(asdf)"_M) << std::endl;
// (will print 5)
constexpr std::string_view str = R"(
  foo
  bar
)"_M;
// str == "foo\nbar"

// also works with wchar_t, char8_t, char16_t and char32_t literals:
std::wcout << LR"(
  foo
  bar
)"_M;
std::wcout << std::endl;
```

---

Normally it's not possible to pass string literals as template arguments, e.g.:

```cpp
template<const char* str>
void foo();

// ill-formed
foo<"bar">();
```

But with C++20 we can now have class-type template arguments, and those could be constant-initialized from a string literal.

That in combination with the new [string literal operator templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal#Literal_operators) makes it possible to get the entire string literal as a template parameter:

```cpp
template<class _char_type, std::size_t size>
struct string_wrapper {
    using char_type = _char_type;

    consteval string_wrapper(const char_type (&arr)[size]) {
        std::ranges::copy(arr, str);
    }

    char_type str[size];
};

template<string_wrapper str>
consteval decltype(auto) operator"" _M() {
    /*...*/
}

// R"(foobar)"_M
// would now result in the following code:
// operator"" _M<string_wrapper<char, 7>{"foobar"}>()
```

Having both the length and the individual characters as constant expressions enables us now to compute the required size for the unindented string fully at compile-time and storing the resulting string in another template parameter (so that we merely need to return a reference to the final string value):

```cpp
// unindents the individual lines of a raw string literal
// e.g. unindent_string("  \n  a\n  b\n  c\n") -> "a\nb\nc"
template<class char_type>
consteval std::vector<char_type> unindent_string(string_view<char_type> str) {
    /* ... */
}

// returns the size required for the unindented string
template<class char_type>
consteval std::size_t unindent_string_size(string_view<char_type> str) {
    /* ... */
}

// used for sneakily creating and storing
// the unindented string in a template parameter.
template<string_wrapper sw>
struct unindented_string_wrapper {
    using char_type = typename decltype(sw)::char_type;
    static constexpr std::size_t buffer_size = unindent_string_size<char_type>(sw.str);
    using array_ref = const char_type (&)[buffer_size];

    consteval unindented_string_wrapper(int) {
        auto newstr = unindent_string<char_type>(sw.str);
        std::ranges::copy(newstr, buffer);
    }

    consteval array_ref get() const {
        return buffer;
    }

    char_type buffer[buffer_size];
};

// uses a defaulted template argument that depends on the str
// to initialize the unindented string within a template parameter.
// this enables us to return a reference to the unindented string.
template<string_wrapper str, unindented_string_wrapper<str> unindented = 0>
consteval decltype(auto) do_unindent() {
    return unindented.get();
}

// the actual user-defined string literal operator
template<string_wrapper str>
consteval decltype(auto) operator"" _M() {
    return do_unindent<str>();
}
```

---

Full Code: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rMv49c3x4)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

namespace multiline_raw_string {
    template<class char_type>
    using string_view = std::basic_string_view<char_type>;

    // characters that are considered space
    // we need this because std::isspace is not constexpr
    template<class char_type>
    constexpr string_view<char_type> space_chars = std::declval<string_view<char_type>>();
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char> space_chars<char> = " \f\n\r\t\v";
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<wchar_t> space_chars<wchar_t> = L" \f\n\r\t\v";
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char8_t> space_chars<char8_t> = u8" \f\n\r\t\v";
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char16_t> space_chars<char16_t> = u" \f\n\r\t\v";
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char32_t> space_chars<char32_t> = U" \f\n\r\t\v";
    
    
    // list of all potential line endings that could be encountered
    template<class char_type>
    constexpr string_view<char_type> potential_line_endings[] = std::declval<string_view<char_type>[]>();
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char> potential_line_endings<char>[] = {
        "\r\n",
        "\r",
        "\n"
    };
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<wchar_t> potential_line_endings<wchar_t>[] = {
        L"\r\n",
        L"\r",
        L"\n"
    };
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char8_t> potential_line_endings<char8_t>[] = {
        u8"\r\n",
        u8"\r",
        u8"\n"
    };
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char16_t> potential_line_endings<char16_t>[] = {
        u"\r\n",
        u"\r",
        u"\n"
    };
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char32_t> potential_line_endings<char32_t>[] = {
        U"\r\n",
        U"\r",
        U"\n"
    };

    // null-terminator for the different character types
    template<class char_type>
    constexpr char_type null_char = std::declval<char_type>();
    template<>
    constexpr char null_char<char> = '\0';
    template<>
    constexpr wchar_t null_char<wchar_t> = L'\0';
    template<>
    constexpr char8_t null_char<char8_t> = u8'\0';
    template<>
    constexpr char16_t null_char<char16_t> = u'\0';
    template<>
    constexpr char32_t null_char<char32_t> = U'\0';

    // detects the line ending used within a string.
    // e.g. detect_line_ending("foo\nbar\nbaz") -> "\n"
    template<class char_type>
    consteval string_view<char_type> detect_line_ending(string_view<char_type> str) {
        return *std::ranges::max_element(
            potential_line_endings<char_type>,
            {},
            [str](string_view<char_type> line_ending) {
                // count the number of lines we would get with line_ending
                auto view = std::views::split(str, line_ending);
                return std::ranges::distance(view);
            }
        );
    }

    // returns a view to the leading sequence of space characters within a string
    // e.g. get_leading_space_sequence(" \t  foo") -> " \t  "
    template<class char_type>
    consteval string_view<char_type> get_leading_space_sequence(string_view<char_type> line) {
        return line.substr(0, line.find_first_not_of(space_chars<char_type>));
    }

    // checks if a line consists purely out of space characters
    // e.g. is_line_empty("    \t") -> true
    //      is_line_empty("   foo") -> false
    template<class char_type>
    consteval bool is_line_empty(string_view<char_type> line) {
        return get_leading_space_sequence(line).size() == line.size();
    }

    // splits a string into individual lines
    // and removes the first & last line if they are empty
    // e.g. split_lines("\na\nb\nc\n", "\n") -> {"a", "b", "c"}
    template<class char_type>
    consteval std::vector<string_view<char_type>> split_lines(
        string_view<char_type> str,
        string_view<char_type> line_ending
    ) {
        std::vector<string_view<char_type>> lines;

        for (auto line : std::views::split(str, line_ending)) {
            lines.emplace_back(line.begin(), line.end());
        }

        // remove first/last lines in case they are completely empty
        if(lines.size() > 1 && is_line_empty(lines[0])) {
            lines.erase(lines.begin());
        }
        if(lines.size() > 1 && is_line_empty(lines[lines.size()-1])) {
            lines.erase(lines.end()-1);
        }

        return lines;
    }

    // determines the longest possible sequence of space characters
    // that we can remove from each line.
    // e.g. determine_common_space_prefix_sequence({" \ta", " foo", " \t\ŧbar"}) -> " "
    template<class char_type>
    consteval string_view<char_type> determine_common_space_prefix_sequence(
        std::vector<string_view<char_type>> const& lines
    ) {
        std::vector<string_view<char_type>> space_sequences = {
            string_view<char_type>{} // empty string
        };

        for(string_view<char_type> line : lines) {
            string_view<char_type> spaces = get_leading_space_sequence(line);
            for(std::size_t len = 1; len <= spaces.size(); len++) {
                space_sequences.emplace_back(spaces.substr(0, len));
            }
   
            // remove duplicates
            std::ranges::sort(space_sequences);
            auto [first, last] = std::ranges::unique(space_sequences);
            space_sequences.erase(first, last);
        }

        // only consider space prefix sequences that apply to all lines
        auto shared_prefixes = std::views::filter(
            space_sequences,
            [&lines](string_view<char_type> prefix) {
                return std::ranges::all_of(
                    lines,
                    [&prefix](string_view<char_type> line) {
                        return line.starts_with(prefix);
                    }
                );
            }
        );

        // select the longest possible space prefix sequence
        return *std::ranges::max_element(
            shared_prefixes,
            {},
            &string_view<char_type>::size
        );
    }

    // unindents the individual lines of a raw string literal
    // e.g. unindent_string("  \n  a\n  b\n  c\n") -> "a\nb\nc"
    template<class char_type>
    consteval std::vector<char_type> unindent_string(string_view<char_type> str) {
        string_view<char_type> line_ending = detect_line_ending(str);
        std::vector<string_view<char_type>> lines = split_lines(str, line_ending);
        string_view<char_type> common_space_sequence = determine_common_space_prefix_sequence(lines);

        std::vector<char_type> new_string;
        bool is_first = true;
        for(auto line : lines) {
            // append newline
            if(is_first) {
                is_first = false;
            } else {
                new_string.insert(new_string.end(), line_ending.begin(), line_ending.end());
            }

            // append unindented line
            auto unindented = line.substr(common_space_sequence.size());
            new_string.insert(new_string.end(), unindented.begin(), unindented.end());
        }

        // add null terminator
        new_string.push_back(null_char<char_type>);

        return new_string;
    }

    // returns the size required for the unindented string
    template<class char_type>
    consteval std::size_t unindent_string_size(string_view<char_type> str) {
        return unindent_string(str).size();
    }

    // simple type that stores a raw string
    // we need this to get around the limitation that string literals
    // are not considered valid non-type template arguments.
    template<class _char_type, std::size_t size>
    struct string_wrapper {
        using char_type = _char_type;

        consteval string_wrapper(const char_type (&arr)[size]) {
            std::ranges::copy(arr, str);
        }

        char_type str[size];
    };

    // used for sneakily creating and storing
    // the unindented string in a template parameter.
    template<string_wrapper sw>
    struct unindented_string_wrapper {
        using char_type = typename decltype(sw)::char_type;
        static constexpr std::size_t buffer_size = unindent_string_size<char_type>(sw.str);
        using array_ref = const char_type (&)[buffer_size];

        consteval unindented_string_wrapper(int) {
            auto newstr = unindent_string<char_type>(sw.str);
            std::ranges::copy(newstr, buffer);
        }

        consteval array_ref get() const {
            return buffer;
        }

        char_type buffer[buffer_size];
    };

    // uses a defaulted template argument that depends on the str
    // to initialize the unindented string within a template parameter.
    // this enables us to return a reference to the unindented string.
    template<string_wrapper str, unindented_string_wrapper<str> unindented = 0>
    consteval decltype(auto) do_unindent() {
        return unindented.get();
    }

    // the actual user-defined string literal operator
    template<string_wrapper str>
    consteval decltype(auto) operator"" _M() {
        return do_unindent<str>();
    }
}

using multiline_raw_string::operator"" _M;
```

Comment: Nice!  It's amazing how much work can now get done at compilation time in modern C++.  The Python standard library has a nice name `dedent` for this operation -- https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent

Comment: "with C++20 we can now have class-type template arguments" -- could you please provide some reference to that?

Comment: @IgorR. [Literal class types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType) can be used as [non-type template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) since C++20. ([Here's a small example](https://ctrpeach.io/posts/cpp20-class-as-non-type-template-param/)). The paper that added this to the standard was [P0732R2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0732r2.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem and I think the following solution is the best of all the above. I hope it'll be helpful for you, too (see example in the comment):

```cpp
/**
 * Strips a multi-line string's indentation prefix.
 *
 * Example:
 * \code
 *   string s = R"(|line one
 *                 |line two
 *                 |line three
 *                 |)"_multiline;
 *   std::cout << s;
 * \endcode
 *
 * This prints three lines: @c "line one\nline two\nline three\n"
 *
 * @author Christian Parpart <christian@parpart.family>
 */

inline std::string operator ""_multiline(const char* text, unsigned long size) {
  if (!*text)
    return {};

  enum class State {
    LineData,
    SkipUntilPrefix,
  };

  constexpr char LF = '\n';
  State state = State::LineData;
  std::stringstream sstr;
  char sep = *text++;

  while (*text) {
    switch (state) {
      case State::LineData: {
        if (*text == LF) {
          state = State::SkipUntilPrefix;
          sstr << *text++;
        } else {
          sstr << *text++;
        }
        break;
      }
      case State::SkipUntilPrefix: {
        if (*text == sep) {
          state = State::LineData;
          text++;
        } else {
          text++;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return sstr.str();
}
```

Comment: I don't see `_multiline` in the example, has the code drifted away from the comments?

Comment: Nice code.  I still like the current `1 + ` solution because it can also be used to assign to a `constexpr char*`.

Comment: @Hugues, you may still use the constexpr_string class within that code (instead of std::stringstream), but I believe, this functionality should definitely be in the C++ standard library instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that is annoying. Perhaps there should be raw literals (`R"PREFIX("`) and *multiline* raw literals (`M"PREFIX`).

I came up with this alternative which almost describes itself:

```
#include<iterator> // std::next
...
{
    ...
    ...
    std::string atoms_text = 
std::next/*_line*/(R"XYZ(
  O123        12.4830720891       13.1055820441        9.5288258996
  O123        13.1055820441       13.1055820441        9.5288258996
)XYZ");
    assert( atoms_text[0] != '\n' );
    ...
}
```

Limitations:

1. If the raw literal is empty it will generate an invalid string. But that should be obvious to spot.
2. If the raw literal doesn't start with a new line it will eat the first character instead.
3. `std::next` is `constexpr` only from C++17, you then can use `1+(char const*)R"XYZ("` but it is not as clear and might produce warning.

```
constexpr auto atom_text = 1 + (R"XYZ(
  O123        12.4830720891       13.1055820441        9.5288258996
  O123        13.1055820441       13.1055820441        9.5288258996
)XYZ");
```

Also, no warranties ;) . After all, I don't know if it is legal to do arithmetic with pointers to static data.

---

Another advantage of the `+ 1` approach is that it can be put at the end:

```
constexpr auto atom_text = R"XYZ(
  O123        12.4830720891       13.1055820441        9.5288258996
  O123        13.1055820441       13.1055820441        9.5288258996
)XYZ" + 1;
```

---

Possibilities are endless:

```
constexpr auto atom_text = &R"XYZ(
  O123        12.4830720891       13.1055820441        9.5288258996
  O123        13.1055820441       13.1055820441        9.5288258996
)XYZ"[1];
```

```
constexpr auto atom_text = &1[R"XYZ(
  O123        12.4830720891       13.1055820441        9.5288258996
  O123        13.1055820441       13.1055820441        9.5288258996
)XYZ"];
```

Comment: _"I don't know if it is legal to do arithmetic with pointers to static data"_ — surely it is. No matter where the array is, you can iterate over its elements, and one of the ways to do it is to traverse the array with a pointer.