# Indentation aware raw string literals

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, string-literals

Is there a way to have raw string literals that is aware of the indentation?

e.g.

```
{
    std::string_view str(
    R"(
       Hello
           World
    )");
    std::cout << "ref\n" << str;
}
```

prints

```
ref

       Hello
           World
```

but I would like

```
ref
Hello
    World
```

I see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900770/2689696) solves this, but it is run time.
With c23 I think `#embed` might solve this.

But Is there a way to so this at compile time, preferably with c++17, c++20 is okay too.

Comment: If `c++17` is the preferred standard that you people to use in the answers then don't list `c++20` as well.

Comment: Using raw string literals there's really no nice (and compile-time) way to do what you want.

Comment: Why not `"ref\nHello\n    World\n"`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Its mainly for readability.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to do what you want (or something similar) with C++20 user-defined string literals.

Comment: @Hasturkun it's indeed possible with user-defined literals: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rMv49c3x4) - but it requires quite a bit of code to handle all potential edge cases like different line-endings, which characters are considered spaces, what to do with inconsistent indentation patterns, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### tl;dr

- It is possible to do this in C++20 with a [user-defined literal operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal).
  Example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rMv49c3x4)

  ```cpp
  std::cout << R"(
      Hello
          World
  )"_M << std::endl;
  ```
- It would theoretically also be possible to do this in C++17, but there the syntax would not be as nice:

  ```cpp
  constexpr auto str = unindent(R"(
      Hello
          World!
  )"); // type of str would be std::array<char, N>
  std::cout << str.data() << std::endl;
  ```

---

##### 1. Why a C++17 implementation would be suboptimal

The biggest problem with C++17 in this case is that we need to modify the string (remove spaces within it) - so we need to store the modified string *somewhere*.

In C++20 we can get the string as a template argument, utilizing a [string literal operator template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal#Literal_operators), e.g.:

```cpp
template<class _char_type, std::size_t size>
struct string_wrapper {
    using char_type = _char_type;

    consteval string_wrapper(const char_type (&arr)[size]) {
        std::ranges::copy(arr, str);
    }

    char_type str[size];
};

template<string_wrapper str>
consteval decltype(auto) operator"" _M() {
    return do_unindent<str>();
}

// R"(foo)"_M
// would be interpreted as:
// operator"" _M<string_wrapper{R"(foo)"}>()
```

This allows us to store the unindented-string within a template parameter, so its lifetime will never be a problem; we can directly return a reference to the array stored within the template parameter.

In C++17 on the other hand we can't have class-types as template arguments and the string literal operator template is also not available. So there's no neat way to store the modified string globally (`static` variables are not allowed within constant expressions, so that's not an option)

So the only way to implement this in C++17 would be to return a `std::array` (or something similar):

```cpp
template<std::size_t size>
constexpr auto unindent(const char (&str)[size]) {
    return std::array<char, size>{ /* ... */ };
}
```

That however has a few major downsides:

- You always have to call `.data()` to convert the `std::array` back into a `const char*`:

  ```cpp
  std::cout << unindent(R"(foo)").data() << std::endl;
  ```
- You have to be careful to keep the `std::array` alive:

  ```cpp
  // BAD: Woops: dangling pointer!
  const char* str = unindent(R"(foo)").data();

  // GOOD: keep array alive
  auto arr = unindent(R"(foo)");
  const char* str = arr.data();
  ```
- Note that the array we return would need to be bigger than the actual unindented string (`std::array<char, size>`). Due to `str` being a parameter to the function it is not a constant expression, so we can't use it to determine the actual size of the unindented string (so we only have the length of the original string to work with):

  ```cpp
  constexpr std::array<char, 8> arr = unindent("  a\n  b");
  // arr would be {'a', '\n', 'b', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'};
  ```

  So this would most likely result in a lot of additional `'\0'`'s in your final binary, in addition to being rather confusing (`arr.size()` is not the true length of the string)
- We can't use [user-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) - the only variant that is supported in C++17 would be:

  ```cpp
  constexpr /*...*/ operator"" _M(const char* str, std::size_t len) {
      return std::array<char, 1000> { /* ... */ };
  }
  ```

  ... but with that both the `str` and it's length are no longer constant expressions, so we can use neither for the size of our `std::array`; so the only possible option would be to used a fixed-size array - which is not very useful.

For those reasons i'll only provide a C++20 implementation.

---

##### 2. Full Implementation

This is the full C++20 implementation:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rMv49c3x4)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

namespace multiline_raw_string {
    template<class char_type>
    using string_view = std::basic_string_view<char_type>;

    // characters that are considered space
    // we need this because std::isspace is not constexpr
    template<class char_type>
    constexpr string_view<char_type> space_chars = std::declval<string_view<char_type>>();
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char> space_chars<char> = " \f\n\r\t\v";
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<wchar_t> space_chars<wchar_t> = L" \f\n\r\t\v";
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char8_t> space_chars<char8_t> = u8" \f\n\r\t\v";
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char16_t> space_chars<char16_t> = u" \f\n\r\t\v";
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char32_t> space_chars<char32_t> = U" \f\n\r\t\v";
    
    
    // list of all potential line endings that could be encountered
    template<class char_type>
    constexpr string_view<char_type> potential_line_endings[] = std::declval<string_view<char_type>[]>();
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char> potential_line_endings<char>[] = {
        "\r\n",
        "\r",
        "\n"
    };
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<wchar_t> potential_line_endings<wchar_t>[] = {
        L"\r\n",
        L"\r",
        L"\n"
    };
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char8_t> potential_line_endings<char8_t>[] = {
        u8"\r\n",
        u8"\r",
        u8"\n"
    };
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char16_t> potential_line_endings<char16_t>[] = {
        u"\r\n",
        u"\r",
        u"\n"
    };
    template<>
    constexpr string_view<char32_t> potential_line_endings<char32_t>[] = {
        U"\r\n",
        U"\r",
        U"\n"
    };

    // null-terminator for the different character types
    template<class char_type>
    constexpr char_type null_char = std::declval<char_type>();
    template<>
    constexpr char null_char<char> = '\0';
    template<>
    constexpr wchar_t null_char<wchar_t> = L'\0';
    template<>
    constexpr char8_t null_char<char8_t> = u8'\0';
    template<>
    constexpr char16_t null_char<char16_t> = u'\0';
    template<>
    constexpr char32_t null_char<char32_t> = U'\0';

    // detects the line ending used within a string.
    // e.g. detect_line_ending("foo\nbar\nbaz") -> "\n"
    template<class char_type>
    consteval string_view<char_type> detect_line_ending(string_view<char_type> str) {
        return *std::ranges::max_element(
            potential_line_endings<char_type>,
            {},
            [str](string_view<char_type> line_ending) {
                // count the number of lines we would get with line_ending
                auto view = std::views::split(str, line_ending);
                return std::ranges::distance(view);
            }
        );
    }

    // returns a view to the leading sequence of space characters within a string
    // e.g. get_leading_space_sequence(" \t  foo") -> " \t  "
    template<class char_type>
    consteval string_view<char_type> get_leading_space_sequence(string_view<char_type> line) {
        return line.substr(0, line.find_first_not_of(space_chars<char_type>));
    }

    // checks if a line consists purely out of space characters
    // e.g. is_line_empty("    \t") -> true
    //      is_line_empty("   foo") -> false
    template<class char_type>
    consteval bool is_line_empty(string_view<char_type> line) {
        return get_leading_space_sequence(line).size() == line.size();
    }

    // splits a string into individual lines
    // and removes the first & last line if they are empty
    // e.g. split_lines("\na\nb\nc\n", "\n") -> {"a", "b", "c"}
    template<class char_type>
    consteval std::vector<string_view<char_type>> split_lines(
        string_view<char_type> str,
        string_view<char_type> line_ending
    ) {
        std::vector<string_view<char_type>> lines;

        for (auto line : std::views::split(str, line_ending)) {
            lines.emplace_back(line.begin(), line.end());
        }

        // remove first/last lines in case they are completely empty
        if(lines.size() > 1 && is_line_empty(lines[0])) {
            lines.erase(lines.begin());
        }
        if(lines.size() > 1 && is_line_empty(lines[lines.size()-1])) {
            lines.erase(lines.end()-1);
        }

        return lines;
    }

    // determines the longest possible sequence of space characters
    // that we can remove from each line.
    // e.g. determine_common_space_prefix_sequence({" \ta", " foo", " \t\ŧbar"}) -> " "
    template<class char_type>
    consteval string_view<char_type> determine_common_space_prefix_sequence(
        std::vector<string_view<char_type>> const& lines
    ) {
        std::vector<string_view<char_type>> space_sequences = {
            string_view<char_type>{} // empty string
        };

        for(string_view<char_type> line : lines) {
            string_view<char_type> spaces = get_leading_space_sequence(line);
            for(std::size_t len = 1; len <= spaces.size(); len++) {
                space_sequences.emplace_back(spaces.substr(0, len));
            }
   
            // remove duplicates
            std::ranges::sort(space_sequences);
            auto [first, last] = std::ranges::unique(space_sequences);
            space_sequences.erase(first, last);
        }

        // only consider space prefix sequences that apply to all lines
        auto shared_prefixes = std::views::filter(
            space_sequences,
            [&lines](string_view<char_type> prefix) {
                return std::ranges::all_of(
                    lines,
                    [&prefix](string_view<char_type> line) {
                        return line.starts_with(prefix);
                    }
                );
            }
        );

        // select the longest possible space prefix sequence
        return *std::ranges::max_element(
            shared_prefixes,
            {},
            &string_view<char_type>::size
        );
    }

    // unindents the individual lines of a raw string literal
    // e.g. unindent_string("  \n  a\n  b\n  c\n") -> "a\nb\nc"
    template<class char_type>
    consteval std::vector<char_type> unindent_string(string_view<char_type> str) {
        string_view<char_type> line_ending = detect_line_ending(str);
        std::vector<string_view<char_type>> lines = split_lines(str, line_ending);
        string_view<char_type> common_space_sequence = determine_common_space_prefix_sequence(lines);

        std::vector<char_type> new_string;
        bool is_first = true;
        for(auto line : lines) {
            // append newline
            if(is_first) {
                is_first = false;
            } else {
                new_string.insert(new_string.end(), line_ending.begin(), line_ending.end());
            }

            // append unindented line
            auto unindented = line.substr(common_space_sequence.size());
            new_string.insert(new_string.end(), unindented.begin(), unindented.end());
        }

        // add null terminator
        new_string.push_back(null_char<char_type>);

        return new_string;
    }

    // returns the size required for the unindented string
    template<class char_type>
    consteval std::size_t unindent_string_size(string_view<char_type> str) {
        return unindent_string(str).size();
    }

    // simple type that stores a raw string
    // we need this to get around the limitation that string literals
    // are not considered valid non-type template arguments.
    template<class _char_type, std::size_t size>
    struct string_wrapper {
        using char_type = _char_type;

        consteval string_wrapper(const char_type (&arr)[size]) {
            std::ranges::copy(arr, str);
        }

        char_type str[size];
    };

    // used for sneakily creating and storing
    // the unindented string in a template parameter.
    template<string_wrapper sw>
    struct unindented_string_wrapper {
        using char_type = typename decltype(sw)::char_type;
        static constexpr std::size_t buffer_size = unindent_string_size<char_type>(sw.str);
        using array_ref = const char_type (&)[buffer_size];

        consteval unindented_string_wrapper(int) {
            auto newstr = unindent_string<char_type>(sw.str);
            std::ranges::copy(newstr, buffer);
        }

        consteval array_ref get() const {
            return buffer;
        }

        char_type buffer[buffer_size];
    };

    // uses a defaulted template argument that depends on the str
    // to initialize the unindented string within a template parameter.
    // this enables us to return a reference to the unindented string.
    template<string_wrapper str, unindented_string_wrapper<str> unindented = 0>
    consteval decltype(auto) do_unindent() {
        return unindented.get();
    }

    // the actual user-defined string literal operator
    template<string_wrapper str>
    consteval decltype(auto) operator"" _M() {
        return do_unindent<str>();
    }
}

using multiline_raw_string::operator"" _M;
```

Usage Example: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rMv49c3x4)

```cpp
std::cout << R"(
     a
    b
     c
    d
)"_M << std::endl;
/* Will print the following:
 a
b
 c
d
*/

// The type of R"(...)"_M is still const char (&)[N],
// so it can be used like a normal string literal:
std::cout << std::size(R"(asdf)"_M) << std::endl;
// (will print 5)

// Lifetime is not a problem; can be stored in a std::string_view:
constexpr std::string_view str = R"(
    foo
    bar
)"_M;

// also works with wchar_t, char8_t, char16_t and char32_t literals:
std::wcout << LR"(foo)"_M << std::endl;
```

---

##### 3. Implementation Notes

- What characters are considered spaces?
  [`std::isspace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) is unfortunately not constexpr, so we have to roll our own: (you can add additional characters that you want to be considered as "space" for the purpose of unindenting):

  ```cpp
  template<>
  constexpr string_view<char> space_chars<char> = " \f\n\r\t\v";
  ```
- Line Endings.
  The line endings within the raw string literal depend on the line-endings used within the source code; there's unfortunately no nice way to get the compiler to tell us what line-endings are in use (there might even be mixed ones within a single source file) - so we have to detect manually what type of line endings are present in the string literal.
  I've implemented `\r\n`, `\n` and `\r` as potential line endings, those should cover most use-cases:

  ```cpp
  template<>
  constexpr string_view<char> potential_line_endings<char>[] = {
      "\r\n",
      "\r",
      "\n"
  };
  ```
- Dealing with mixed indentation
  The space-characters used for indentation must be identical on each line, otherwise they won't be removed. - so you use whatever space character you like for indentation (and even mix them) - as long as you're consistent across all lines.
  e.g. this would not work:

  ```cpp
  // mixed indentation (indentation will remain)
  constexpr std::string_view str = R"(
  <tab>foo
       bar
  )"_M;
  ```

  but this will:

  ```cpp
  // all lines have the same indentation pattern
  constexpr std::string_view str = R"(
  <tab>  foo
  <tab>  bar
  )"_M;
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I see that it works with latest gcc and msvc,  but clang15 seems to have some issue with this.

Comment: @tejas most likely due to some C++20 features still missing / bugs in clang 15. It does work with [clang trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/z34fPK4da).

Comment: @tejas i managed to find a matching bug report - so this seems to be a known (and fixed in trunk) bug in clang 15. Here are the relevant clang issues: [#59697](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/59697) - [#44178](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/44178)

Answer (score 2):

There's always implicit string literal concatenation.  You still need the `\n` characters, but the relative positions of lines are clear.

```
{
    std::string_view str(
        "Hello\n"
        "    World\n"
    );
    std::cout << "ref\n" << str;
}
```